# How to use a wallet as a payment method in stripe with pure PHP?

Tags: php, stripe-payments

I've read and re-read the stripe API documentation, and I'm only working with PHP to set a payment, I got satisfactory results with paying with, `card, afterpay, alipay ...` however when it comes to wallets I didn't understand anything, I noticed that the wallet collects data from the saved cards but when it comes to PHP the documentation doesn't explain anything regarding wallets, They just say you can use `Stripe.js` but i don't want to use js to get the payment data, i want to use `pure php`, but when it comes to PHP nothing is mentioned. Does anyone have any idea how the PHP paymentMethod to collect the wallets? I'm collecting payment data like this:

**CARD**

```
$payment = $stripe->paymentMethods->create([
            'type' => 'card',
            'billing_details' => [
                'address' => [
                    'city' => 'nova york',
                    'country' => 'US',
                    'line1' => 'asdasd',
                    'line2' => 'asdfasd',
                    'postal_code' => '999876',
                    'state' => 'boom'
                ],
            ],
            'card' => [
                'number' => '4242424242424242',
                'exp_month' => 9,
                'exp_year' => 2022,
                'cvc' => '314',
            ],
            'customer' => 'cus_...'
        ]);
```

**AFTERPAY**

```
$payment = $stripe->paymentMethods->create([

        'type' => 'afterpay_clearpay',
        'billing_details' => [
            'address' => [
                'city' => 'Miami',
                'country' => 'US',
                'line1' => 'Street 33',
                'line2' => 'United aLA',
                'postal_code' => '99854332',
                'state' => 'Florida'
            ],
            'email' => 'jenny@example.com',
            'name' => 'Lois',
            'phone' => '+15555555555'
        ],
        'metadata' => ['id' => 'corrego']
    ]);
```

**EPS**

```
$payment = $stripe->paymentMethods->create([
        'type' => 'eps',
        'billing_details' => [
            'address' => [
                'city' => 'Miami',
                'country' => 'BR',
                'line1' => 'Street 33',
                'line2' => 'United aLA',
                'postal_code' => '99854332',
                'state' => 'SP'
            ],
            'email' => 'jenny@example.com',
            'name' => 'Lois',
            'phone' => '+15555555555'
        ],
    ]);
```

...

These methods are explained in the documentation on how to implement both Stripe.js and pure PHP, but wallets they don't even mention a way to do it in pure PHP, does anyone have any notions? My native language is not english so maybe this is making it a little difficult to understand the documentation

Comment: PHP runs on the server, not the browser. Therefore it has no way to interact with browser features such as wallet integrations. If you want features that run in-browser you have to use Javascript. Full stop.

Comment: @Sammitch Are wallet integrations only allowed in the browser anyway?

Comment: The _point_ of the set of standards known as Web Payments is that it happens in the browser. The user gets a unified UI presented there, that looks the same no matter what payment method they will eventually chose.

Comment: You have to do things on the client side (and use stripe.js)for PCI compliance reasons too. If you send raw card numbers from your serverside PHP code you'd need to be PCI certified (https://stripe.com/docs/security/guide#validating-pci-compliance under "API direct"). That's why _all_ Stripe's documentation is pointing you towards using client-side code in the browser and JavaScript. Stripe/payments is a full stack integration, you can't do everything purely in PHP.